# I want to learn algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I did study applied math and dealed almost exclusively with the creation of ode/pde solver code. Now, I want to increase my knowledge in some aspects and I want to learn some basic algorithms like A*, MinMax, ... (not limited to searching; I am also interested in the basics of optimization and machine learning) **and** their implementation.

Is there a good resource (book, online course) available for me to learn this from? Any help is appreciated. I have no other CS-related background except my math degree.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. Since you're happy with mathematics, the book by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein ("Introduction to Algorithms") is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I'll second the suggestion of Introduction to Algorithms. It is *the* book on algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the textbook (from my undergrad years, many years ago):

Bazaraa, M. S.; Jarvis, J. J.; and Sherali, H. D. (1990). Linear Programming and Network Flows. 2nd Edition. New York: John Wiley.

Consider the recent edition of the textbook too.